# Checking needed parameters of stored procedure with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, powershell

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2 that requires some parameters to be run.

Is there a way I can dynamically check the stored procedure to see which parameters are needed? It is being called via `invoke-sqlcmd` in powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three ways to get information about stored procedure parameters.

Experiment with

```
exec sp_help <sproc>

select * from information_schema.parameters where specific_name='<sproc>'

exec sp_sproc_columns <sproc>
```

and see which suits your needs best.